# Exception while referencing a .Net standard 2.0 project from WPF application

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I am getting the following exception while referencing a .Net standard 2.0 project from WPF application developed using .Net framework 4.6.1 project

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As of today (using VisualStudio 2017 15.8.4) this still seems to be a common problem:

Transitive dependencies are not correctly handled with the package management format which uses the `packages.config` file to reference dependencies.

The problem is that VisualStudio 2017 still uses this *old* package management format by default when you create a new WPF desktop project.

#### Solution

The solution is to migrate the project references from `packages.config` file to the *new* `PackageReference` node in the `.csproj` project file.

VisualStudio can do this migration automatically for you. The migration is documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

Please note that there is a known issue:

The `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...` option is not available in the right-click context menu until `NuGet`was initialized.

Another option if your project does not have any package references at all is to change the setting of `RestoreProjectStyle` to `PackageReference` in your `.csproj` file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#using-packagereference-for-a-project-with-no-packagereferences

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Add reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package in your WPF project.